# How can I search for a string inside a .txt file and print the line where the string is in? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, printing, console

Question above. I'm trying to create a contact book inside of the console in Python 3, and i'm trying to implement a "search" command, but everything i've tried didn't work. I didn't find anything helpful on the internet either.

```
f = open("C:/Users/Yonas/Documents/PythonProject.txt", "a")
entry = input()
i = 0

def add():
    print("Please type in the name of the person you want to add.")
    in2 = input()
    f.write(in2 + " | ")

    print("Please type in the location of the person you want to add.")
    in3 = input()
    f.write(in3 + " | ")

    print("Please type in some additional information.")
    in4 = input()
    f.write(in4 + "\n")

def search():
    line_number = 0
    print("Please type in the name of the person you're looking for.")
    inSearch = input()
    list_of_results = list(f)
    
    # The code should be here

if entry.startswith("add"):
    add()

if entry.startswith("search"):
    search()
```

Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Hello there, have you checked this [link][1] which I believe answers your question or might help.


  [1]: https://thispointer.com/python-search-strings-in-a-file-and-get-line-numbers-of-lines-containing-the-string/

Answer (score 0):

A slightly reworked version of your original snippet:

```py
contact_book_path = "collection.txt"


def add():
    with open(contact_book_path, "a") as contact_book_fp:
        contact = ""

        name = input("Please type in the name of the person you want to add.\n")
        contact += name + " | "

        location = input("Please type in the location of the person you want to add.\n")
        contact += location + " | "

        info = input("Please type in some additional information.\n")
        contact += info + "\n"

        contact_book_fp.write(contact)


def search():

    with open(contact_book_path, "r") as contact_book_fp:
        name_search = input(
            "Please type in the name of the person you're looking for.\n"
        )

        for line_no, contact in enumerate(contact_book_fp.readlines()):
            name, location, info = contact.split(" | ")

            if name == name_search:
                print("Your contact was found at line " + str(line_no))
                return

        print("Your contact was not found! :(")


entry = input("What kind of operation would you like to do (add/search)?\n")
if entry.startswith("add"):
    add()

if entry.startswith("search"):
    search()
```

Instead of having the file open in and in append mode, I'd suggest you to open it for the right operation when you really need it.
So for appending in `add` and for reading in `search`.

In the `search` function after opening the file and asking for the name to search for, you can use the standard `file.readlines()` method to iterate through the lines in a file. Also I used the `enumerate` function to get a running index together with a line, and I can use it as the line number later on.

Having put all these together, you can basically enhance the lookup logic any way you want.